# How to avoid certain files with Visual Studio find?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When doing a find in Visual Studio, you can search for specific text in a project or solution.  The problem is it will search all files.

If you want to find "exception" in only C# files, you might have to click through a few minutes of JS files before you get to any relevant files.

Does anyone know how to exclude certain file types in the find?  Or is there a better tool that also restricts by project and solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit, find and replace, find in files ((control shift F)) - specify the look in (current project, entire solution, etc.) and also your file types - you can select from the dropdown (e.g. *.vb;*.resx;*.resw;*.xsd;*.wsdl;*.xaml;*.xml;*.htm;*.html;*.css) and then change them as required.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to open Find in Files.
You can then specify which filetypes to search.